# Query MS Access database in VB 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, ms-access

I added an Access database as a Data Source in VB 2008. I want to query this database and use the information in various ways throughout the program. For example, there is an Employee table with first/last names of employees. I have a combobox on my form that I want to display all of the employees. So I want to query the database for all the rows in the Employee table, and add them to the combobox as I go.

I am familiar with SQL Syntax, so I am not asking how to write the query itself, but rather how to fetch rows in VB code (mimicking php's mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_connect essentially)

Thanks!

Edit: Also, I want to know if I can query a DB if I don't add it as a data source (if I know the path name of the database)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the classes in the `System.Data.OleDb` namespace to query access databases:

```
Using cn As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT query with ? parameter here", cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Int).Value = 1234

    MyCombobox.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
End Using
```