# SQL query variables in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

When writing a query for SQL Server, you can declare and use variables like this:

```
declare @test int
select @test = max(ID) from MyTable1
update MyTable2 set (...) where ID > @test
update MyTable3 set (...) where ID < @test
```

Is there a way to declare and use variables similarly when writing a query for MS Access?

I need to populate the variable with the result of another query and then use that value to perform insert/update operations. The query will be run from a .NET app.

Comment: In Access, you have at least 2 queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a way

```
parameters @test int;
select * from MyTable where ID = @test
```

However, you cannot use `set @test = 1234`, the parameter can be manually entered when the query is run or set in VBA.

**Joel Coehoorn

In [Query MS Access database in VB 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930551/query-ms-access-database-in-vb-2008)**

> You use the classes in the System.Data.OleDb namespace to query access
>   databases:

```
Using cn As New OleDbConnection("connection string here"), _
      cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT query with ? parameter here", cn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Int).Value = 1234

    MyCombobox.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
End Using
```

**Further Notes re Edit to OP**

Query 1

```
update MyTable2 set (...) where ID > (select max(test) from table1)
```

Query 2

```
update MyTable3 set (...) where ID < (select max(test) from table1)
```

Comment: I need to populate `@test` from within the query. Also, the query will be run from a .NET app, not VBA.

Comment: If you are running from a Net app you can Add Parameters.

Comment: eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930551/query-ms-access-database-in-vb-2008

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use `@` as a prefix for parameter names in Access. I Usually use `:` as the prefix because it is Standard SQL or `arg_` because it shows up better in online forums ;)

Comment: Removing the @ seemed to me to cloud the issue, especially as it will not break anything. If you paste the above two lines into the query design window, the ampersand in the parameter name is removed on save and int is changed to long, but it will run on paste. Similary, if you use the lines as the basis of a querydef, the query will execute.