# Access form update extremely slow due to VBA function in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a form `DW_Query_subform` which displays the output of a Query `qryDataExport`, which gathers the content of another Query `DW_Query` and provides a further filter (WHERE) through a VBA function `ToDouble(inputValue As Variant) As Double`.

```
Function ToDouble(inputValue As Variant) As Double
    If (IsNull(inputValue)) Then inputValue = "59999" 'If we have no input, assume the area being covered is the whole Earth.
    ToDouble = CDbl(inputValue)
End Function
```

When this function is removed from the query, it runs reasonably quickly. (Taking less than one second to complete.) However, when `WHERE (((DW_Query.Distance)<ToDouble([Forms]![DW_Form]![Radius])))` is added to the query, it generally takes upwards of ten seconds to complete.

Radius is here a TextBox control on a form `DW_Form` of which `DW_Query_subform` is a subform. In the test cases, the form either contains "8" or is blank.

The slowdown occurs even when `DW_Query` contains less than 100 rows. (Tests have been performed in which the parent query has as few as ZERO rows, with consistent results.)

What might be causing this slowdown? Full query below.

```
SELECT DW_Query.Map_Number, DW_Query.Map_Name, DW_Query.Map_Type, 
DW_Query.Town, DW_Query.Address, DW_Query.Street, DW_Query.Block, 
DW_Query.Lot, DW_Query.group, DW_Query.Folder, DW_Query.Distance
FROM DW_Query
WHERE ((DW_Query.Distance)<ToDouble([Forms]![DW_Form]![Radius]));
```

I have attempted to follow Gustav's recommendations below, but when referencing the newly-created table, the query will not update and display properly. (All fields appear blank except one, which displays only `\`, which is meant to show between the concatenated content of two other fields.)

Update: The problem does NOT lie with the use of the ToDouble function, or in the comparison in `qryDataExport`'s WHERE clause, as removing both of these things does not result in a noticeable improvement; I'm afraid that leaves me clueless.

Comment: "When this function is removed from the query, it runs reasonably quickly." vs "Update: The problem does NOT lie with the use of the ToDouble function"  I'm confused... what made you thing that removing the function earlier caused an increase in performance?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, at this point. Initially, when I removed the call to ToDouble there was a visible performance improvement. Later attempts did not show the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
WHERE ((DW_Query.Distance)<Nz([Forms]![DW_Form]![Radius], 5999))
```

but it wouldn't run faster as the value of Radius is called once only.

If you don't have an index on Distance, then try adding it.

Comment: It seems as if `CREATE INDEX` is only available on tables; should `DW_Query` be a Make-Table query, then? It's currently a selection query. (Further, attempting to change it to make-table crashes Access, so I'm afraid that's out of the question.)

Comment: The index should be applied on the table holding the field Distance.

Comment: Distance is not currently in a table; it is generated by DW_Query. I have added another query to convert the output of DW_Query into a table DW_Table, and will attempt to run qryDataExport on that instead. Where should the `CREATE INDEX` statement be?

Comment: In Access index can only be created on a table field.

Comment: I may have phrased the followup badly; where in the SQL statement do I place CREATE INDEX?

Comment: It has become clear that, for whatever reason, running `qryDataExport` on the new `DW_Table` instead of the results of `DW_Query` (Which are the same, theoretically) results in a data set that will not display properly on my form, so unfortunately this will not work.

Comment: You must create the index before running the select query. It is two processes.

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge of access is very poor, but... why don't you do this:

```
dim myDoubleValue as double 
myDoubleValue = ToDouble([Forms]![DW_Form]![Radius])
WHERE DW_Query.Distance < myDoubleValue
```

or, if that doesn't work, you could use the # sign on the variable to specify that this is a double value:

```
dim myDoubleValue#

myDoubleValue# = ToDouble([Forms]![DW_Form]![Radius])

WHERE DW_Query.Distance < myDoubleValue
```

Comment: Can you declare variables that way in SQL? [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491662/sql-query-variables-in-ms-access) says that the syntax is different and that you can't assign them a value in the code itself, instead requiring that users be prompted upon each search.

Comment: @Raul Luna - Access doesn't work that way, it's SQL is really very limited. Instead, one leverages with VBA in a way not so different from using any other language that isn't really an intergral part of a database engine (e.g. via library calls or ODBC etc.). The only help one gets in VBA are predefined objects like `CurrentDb`, etc.

Comment: But this [forms]![dw_form] is a field of a form or is a field of a table?

Comment: `DW_Form` is not a field at all; it is a form, and Radius is a control on that form.

Comment: It is a field of a form, and Access does make use of a VBA expressions engine (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177901(v=office.12).aspx). That, however, is only for inline computations, not for variable declarations or program flow control.